# Loop through Year while skipping certain months

Tags: python, loops, date

I am using the following loop for a monthly time series and I would like to skip the months of May and November:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

for beg in pd.date_range('2014-01-01', '2017-12-31', freq='MS'):
    print(beg.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), (beg + MonthEnd(1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Can anyone suggest an approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple `if` condition to check if month not in check list.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

for beg in pd.date_range('2014-01-01', '2017-12-31', freq='MS'):
    if not beg.month in [5, 11]:
        print(beg.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), (beg + MonthEnd(1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```